# composição e validação

Tags: c++, email, composição

Pessoal tenho uma struct chamada Contact com variaveis std::string

e uma classe pronta de validação de email usando regex.
estou criando um programa e para nao precisar criar outra função de validação para esta classe contact fiz a include da minha classe email entao tenho na minha struct Contact uma função do tipo Contact chamada getContact.

entao fiz algo do tipo abaixo mas esta dando falha de segmentação ou tem como fazer de uma forma melhor para que eu possa resolver isso recebendo dentro do construtor da classe um obeto do tipo contact?

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

struct Contact
{
    std::string eMail;
}; 

class email
{
  std::string _mail;
  Contact e;

 public:

   email(Contact& em): _mail(em.eMail){}

 bool isMail()
 {
  std::smatch email_smatch;

  const std::regex pattern("([a-zA-Z0-9._]+@(?:(?:hotmail|terra|yahoo|bol)[.](?:com[.]br)?)?(?:(?:gmail)[.](?:com)?)?)?");

  return std::regex_match(_mail, email_smatch, pattern);
 }

 email* print()
 { 
   e.eMail = _mail;
   std::cout<<"\n\tEmail: "<<(email(e).isMail()?" is Valid\n":" is Invalid\n"); 
 }
};


Contact getContact()
{
  Contact c;
     do{
        std::cout << "\n\tEnter email: ";
         getline(std::cin, c.eMail);

         email(c).print();

       }while(email(c).print() == 0);
}

int main(void)
{
  getContact();
  std::cout<<"\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é você declarou a função "getContact" como do tipo "Contact" mas no fim da função você não retornou o valor.

Comece a prestar atenção nos warnings!

Comment: ele nao deu nenhum warning especifico em si, só mostrou falha de segmentação mesmo pois antes de executar novamente mudei o tipo da função email* print que daria erro pois estou fazendo retorno entao declarei ela como std::string;